# Show that a subset $W$ of a vector space $V$ is a subspace of $V$ iff $\text{span}(W) = W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Show that a subset $W$ of a vector space $V$ is a subspace of $V$ iff $\text{span}(W) = W$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

We may consider that $W\neq\varnothing$. Otherwise $\text{span}(W) = \{0\} = \varnothing$ which makes no sense.

Suppose that $W\leq V$. Then $x + y \in W$ and $ax\in W$ whenever $x,y\in W$ and $a\in\textbf{F}$.

Consequently, if $w\in\text{span}(W)$, then we have that
\begin{align*}
w = a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} + \ldots + a_{n}x_{n} \in \text{span}(W) \Rightarrow w\in W
\end{align*}

On the other hand, if $w\in W$, then $1w\in\text{span}(W)$, and we are done.

Conversely, let us suppose that $\text{span}(W) = W$.

Then, if we are given $x,y\in W$ and $a\in\textbf{F}$, we have that $x + y \in\text{span}(W) = W$ and $ax\in\text{span}(W) = W$.

Thus we conclude that $W$ is a linear subspace of $V$ and we are done.

Any comments on my solution are welcome.

Comment: $Span(\emptyset) = \{ 0\}$ so it has sense

Comment: Also the usual symbol for subset is $\subseteq.$

Comment: @SahibaArora But $\leq$ means "is a subspace of", not merely "is a subset of". After the edit changing "Suppose that $W \leq V$" to "Suppose that $W \subseteq V$", next statement "Then $x + y \in W$" is no longer valid.

Comment: @Exodd Thanks for pointing it out. But if we consider $W = \varnothing$, then we get that $\text{span}(W) = \text{span}(\varnothing) = \{0\} = \varnothing$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BrickByBrick That last equality $\{0\} = \emptyset$ is not true. $\{0\}$ is the trivial subspace containing one element, the zero vector, whereas $\emptyset$ is the empty set which contains no elements.

Comment: @Bungo That's the point. So we should consider $W\neq\varnothing$, right?

Comment: Why do you have to exclude $W = \emptyset$? It is not a subspace of $V$, and it does not satisfy $\operatorname{span}(W) = W$.

Comment: @Bungo Good point. I wasn't aware $\leq$ is used to denote subspace

Comment: @SahibaArora I'm not sure if $\leq$ for subspace is 100% standard, but I suspect that's the notation used by the OP. (It's common in group theory to denote subgroup vs. subset.)

Comment: @Bungo Yes for subgroups, I am familiar with it.

Comment: You can think of it without any calculation too.
$\\$

For any subset W of a vector space V, span(W) is the smallest subspace containing W. Hence, if W is already a subspace, then W itself is the smallest subspace containing W. Hence,  span(W)=W  if W is a subspace.  
$\\$

If span(W)=W then since by definition span(W) is a subspace, W is a subspace too.

Comment: Your proof looks OK. Minor typo: in the third to last paragraph, $cx$ should be $ax$.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @NitinTomar That's my preferred proof too, and it has a nice universality because it applies almost word for word in many other contexts. But if the OP's definition of "span $W$" is "the set of linear combinations of elements of $W$" as opposed to "the intersection of all subspaces containing $W$", then there's some work to be done before your proof can be applied.

Comment: Using $\le$ for subspace is not standard. Use it by all means, but explain it as many people will wonder for a moment when reading it.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, i agree with you. I should have taken care of the definition used at the very first place. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @copper.hat It's not standard, but it's not nonstandard either. :-) For example, it appears in the first linear algebra book I checked, Steven Roman's [Advanced Linear Algebra](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Linear-Algebra-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387728287). Agree that the OP should define the notation.